# Is there a way (using Lodash or Underscore) to see if a string in an array of strings contains a substring from another array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of strings:

```
["General election 2017: No cut to UK aid spending, says May", "Paris Champs Elysees attack gunman named as Karim Cheurfi", "William and Kate surprise Radio 1 visit", "South Africa bus crash 'kills at least 19 children'", "Len McCluskey re-elected as Unite general secretary", "Cleethorpes car crash captured on CCTV", "Adam Johnson prison video investigated", "Julian Assange's arrest a 'priority' for US attorney general", "Shrewsbury trust warned over baby heart monitoring in 2007", "High heels row: Petition for work dress code law rejected"]
```

I want to see if any string in the above array has a substring from another array:

```
["South Africa", "United States"]
```

If it does, do xyz.

I've tried using _.difference (lodash) and _.intersection (underscore), but I don't think it compares the strings for substrings.

P.S. Sorry for the crazy array strings - they are news articles from a returned JSON.

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

```js
if(_.intersection(arr, check).length > 0){
//do something
}else {
//do something
}
```

you can use indexOf method from javascript

```js
var arr = ["General election 2017: No cut to UK aid spending, says May", "Paris Champs Elysees attack gunman named as Karim Cheurfi", "William and Kate surprise Radio 1 visit", "South Africa bus crash 'kills at least 19 children'", "Len McCluskey re-elected as Unite general secretary", "Cleethorpes car crash captured on CCTV", "Adam Johnson prison video investigated", "Julian Assange's arrest a 'priority' for US attorney general", "Shrewsbury trust warned over baby heart monitoring in 2007", "High heels row: Petition for work dress code law rejected"];
var check = ["southa frice", "usa"];

var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(check[i]) > -1) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(found);
```

Comment: you can do it with lodash as well

Comment: `_.intersection` will compare the exact values so it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner to do this (with ES6 arrow functions, so you might need to rewrite it to regular `function(){}` if you are not transpiling). You dont need `lodash` at all.

```
var a = ["General election 2017: No cut to UK aid spending, says May", "Paris Champs Elysees attack gunman named as Karim Cheurfi", "William and Kate surprise Radio 1 visit", "South Africa bus crash 'kills at least 19 children'", "Len McCluskey re-elected as Unite general secretary", "Cleethorpes car crash captured on CCTV", "Adam Johnson prison video investigated", "Julian Assange's arrest a 'priority' for US attorney general", "Shrewsbury trust warned over baby heart monitoring in 2007", "High heels row: Petition for work dress code law rejected"];
var b = ["South Africa", "United States"];
var match = a.filter(source => b.some(substring => source.includes(substring)));
```

Or with `lodash` (`_.includes` and `_.filter`):

```
var a = ["General election 2017: No cut to UK aid spending, says May", "Paris Champs Elysees attack gunman named as Karim Cheurfi", "William and Kate surprise Radio 1 visit", "South Africa bus crash 'kills at least 19 children'", "Len McCluskey re-elected as Unite general secretary", "Cleethorpes car crash captured on CCTV", "Adam Johnson prison video investigated", "Julian Assange's arrest a 'priority' for US attorney general", "Shrewsbury trust warned over baby heart monitoring in 2007", "High heels row: Petition for work dress code law rejected"];
var b = ["South Africa", "United States"];
var match = _.filter(a, source => b.some(substring => _.includes(source, substring)));
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using [`lodash#intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionWith):

> This method is like `_.intersection` except that it accepts comparator
>   which is invoked to compare elements of arrays. The order and
>   references of result values are determined by the first array. The
>   comparator is invoked with two arguments: `(arrVal, othVal)`.

`_.intersectionWith(news, words, (article, word) => article.includes(word));`

---

#### Using [ES6](http://es6-features.org/):

```
news.filter(article => words.some(word => article.includes(word)));
```

---

#### Using usual Javascript:

```
news.filter(function(article){
    return words.some(function(word){
       return article.indexOf(word) > -1;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.indexOf()
```

It will helps you. Iterate through news array and find the country name **index** is present by iterating country array.